# What can justify 15 seconds of delay to retrive rows from system tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-performance

If I run `select * from sysobjects`, the first time it takes 15 seconds, after that it just takes 0 seconds.
The same occurs with `sp_helptext someAppSP` or other stuff. Server is almost all time at 0% CPU usage.
It is a classic asp App on top of a VM with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86)   Dec 10 2010 10:56:29   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
I am after recent (newly) App's delays. I don't care the mentioned querys by itself.

[image]

Comment: Might be waiting for a lock. Look at waiting tasks whilst the query is slow and see the wait types for that session.

Comment: Cold cache - warm cache?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, yes, may be (I suspect that), but even in that case it is too much for a simple query that return less than 300 rows. Also I wonder who's cache is cold and slow, sql server, os IO, virtualizacion, I want to distinguish that.

Comment: @MartinSmith, but nothing locks sysobjects, at least from the application. There are no tables creations, dumps or alters from de app, may be some temp tables, but not applies here, I think

Comment: that is weird - two things, either it's a client side (I'm guessing UI issue), or something is indeed blocking.  try either running with NOLOCK hint - select * from sysobjects with (NOLOCK) - and then try running from command line using osql.exe -E -S<servername> -Q"select * from sysobjects".

Comment: I will try that.  The tests are made via rdesktop on the server. IIS and SQL for the app run on the same machine. Thanks @Greg!!!